# Changing to fork awesome in an html5up template

Tags: html, css, templates, fork, font-awesome

I am trying to replace font awesome to [Fork Awesome](https://forkaweso.me/Fork-Awesome/) in this html5up template :
https://html5up.net/paradigm-shift

I have changed the name of  the css file to import in the main.css file.
I also download the files from Fork Awesome and put them in the webfonts directory.

But when i try to use the Fork Awesome icons in the index.html file it doesn't work.

I am really not an expert about htmlcss stuff but i understand the code.

Using Fork Awesome in this template

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.